# Usage of Netty's ChannelLocal

Tags: netty

The JavaDocs for Netty explain ChannelLocal to be similar to ThreadLocal, however I've got some questions about it's usage. ThreadLocal is a static class with static methods that access instance-specific objects. ChannelLocal is not static, have a static internal map or have static methods. The documentation doesn't include an example of accessing ChannelLocal or placing an object into ChannelLocal, so I was hoping someone could give me some insight into it's usage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ChannelLocal is used to assign some data to a Channel.

Here's an example:

```
// Declare
public static final ChannelLocal<Integer> data = new ChannelLocal<Integer>();

// Set
data.set(e.getChannel(), 1);

// Get
int a = data.get(e.getChannel());
```

Here's a couple of real life example:

- http://www.assembla.com/code/argonms/subversion/nodes/trunk/src/argonms/center/recv/RemoteServerListener.java?rev=44
- http://eucalyptus.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.6.2/ServiceSinkHandler_8java-source.html

Comment: Interesting. Ok, thanks for the usage examples, I know where to go from here!

Comment: I'm curious why the internal map for ChannelLocal isn't static:

`
    private final ConcurrentMap<Channel, T> map =
        new ConcurrentIdentityWeakKeyHashMap<Channel, T>();
`

If I use a ChannelLocal in two separate classes, I'll need to re-register my ChannelLocal object between those classes. It would make more sense to have an internal static map so if I put something in ChannelLocal for one class, I can get the same object out from another class without having to pass the ChannelLocal around.

Comment: Not sure myself.  You may want to ask the dev's forum: http://groups.google.com/group/netty.  I know that in the latest netty master (upcoming netty 4.0 release), there is discussion on depreciating ChannelLocal and providing a getAttachment/setAttachment on the channel.  https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/101

Comment: Note: inside a WeakKeyHashMap, the value should not reference the key, otherwise the map entry won't be garbage collected.

Comment: The [ChannelHandler javadoc](http://netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.html) also has a great chapter to learn various recommended ways to manage stateful information with some examples.

Comment: @cbliard ChannelLocal was [removed](http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html) in netty 4.0,