# Netty - How to pass information between handlers in the same pipeline

Tags: java, networking, nio, netty

I would like to create a pipeline of handlers such as:

```
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception 
{
    return Channels.pipeline(
            new ObjectEncoder(),
            new ObjectDecoder(),
            new AuthenticationServerHandler(),
            new BusinessLogicServerHandler());
}
```

The key here is that I'd like the `AuthenticationServerHandler` to be able to pass the login information to the `BusinessLogicServerHandler`.

I do understand that you can use an `Attachment`, however that only stores the information for that handler, the other handlers in the pipeline cannot access it. I also noticed there was something called `ChannelLocal` which might do the trick, however I cannot find any real information on how to use it. All I've seen is people create a static instance to it, but how do you retrieve and access the info in another handler? Assuming that's the correct method.

My question is: how you do pass information between handlers in the same pipeline. In the example above, how do I pass the login credentials from the `AuthenticationServerHandler` to the `BusinessLogicServerHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChannelLocal is the way to go atm. Just create an static instance somewhere and then access it from within your handlers by pass the Channel to the set/get method. This way you can share stuff between your channels.

Comment: That's what I understood (more or less in concept), but I haven't found any examples anywhere on exactly how to do this. I'm still a bit fuzzy on the details...

Comment: We are not using it anymore at Apache James Protocols but I think you can get the idea from the old code: 

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/james/protocols/tags/protocols-1.5/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/james/protocols/impl/ChannelAttributeSupport.java?view=markup

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/james/protocols/tags/protocols-1.5/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/james/protocols/impl/AbstractChannelUpstreamHandler.java?view=markup

Comment: Here's an example for ChannelLocal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449663/usage-of-nettys-channellocal

Comment: @Veebs That's the example I was looking at, but how do you access the static final LocalChannel from the other handler? Or more importantly, how do you access the AuthnticationServerHandler from BusinessLogicHandler? That's the part I'm missing....

Comment: @Veebs Also how does that work for storing stateful information since it's a static member?

Comment: From my understanding, you can declare the static in another class that is known to both AuthnticationServerHandler  and BusinessLogicHandler.  It should be OK for stateful information because, the set() and get() both require the channel as a parameter; i.e. the channel is used to return stateful information for that channel.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier did you have a look at the two links I posted? It does exactly what Veebs is telling you.

Comment: I did, but it didn't make sense to me. I finally just understood the link: http://www.assembla.com/code/argonms/subversion/nodes/trunk/src/argonms/center/recv/RemoteServerListener.java?rev=44

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't a fan of the ChannelLocal implementation with the lack of an internal static map, so what I ended up doing was putting my object on the Channel's attachment for now:

```
ctx.getChannel().setAttachment(myobj);
```

Then I make "myobj" basically a context POJO that contains all the information gathered about the request so far.

```
public class RequestContext {
    private String foo = "";

    public String getFoo(){
        return foo;
    }
    public void setFoo(String foo){
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}

RequestContext reqCtx = new RequestContext();
reqCtx.setFoo("Bar");

ctx.getChannel().setAttachment(reqCtx);
reqCtx = (RequestContext)ctx.getChannel().getAttachment();
```

It's not elegant, but it works...

Comment: Yes but the attachment doesn't traverse to the other handlers in your pipeline, which is the issue I'm having.

Comment: The attachement on the Channel does. I'm using it now and it works fine. It goes wherever the channel goes.

Answer (score 0):

I pass information from one handler to the next ones by using dedicated instances to compose the pipeline for each channel, and by having the handlers reference each others within each pipeline.

The passing of information is made the old way, very simply, without any problem.